# Renaming external WiFi network

Tags: network, wifi

Is there a way to rename a WiFi network? Suppose I don't have access to the router, I simply want my computer to recognise that WiFi network with a custom name.

Background: When I connect to my home WiFi I see a lot of WiFi signals named like "wifi2829", "wifi1119", etc. Mine is "wifi1117", which is pretty similar to many other names, so it takes a couple of seconds to figure out where it is in the list. (no, I cannot auto-connect)

Comment: The name is a function of the Router/AP and I have never seen **any** OS that lets you assign it a different name even if if only just for you.

Comment: What device/service is providing the WiFi networks you see in the list? Where are you located?

Comment: It is a home router. To make an analogy with mobile phones, when we get a call from a mobile number 3348877483 we can save it in our contacts so that next time it appears as "mycontact" when we receive a call. I would like to do the same for the wifi network, and rename it "myhomewifi" or similar (only as seen on my mac).